# SVG images not aligned/pixel perfect with surrounding elements (especially jarring when animating!)

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, css-animations, styled-components

I'm trying to create animating, 3-D bars in a bar graph. In order to avoid any stretching/aspect ratio issues, I've broken up each bar into three pieces: (1) an SVG for the top of the bar, (2) a height flexible div for the bar "to animate up," and (3) an SVG for the bottom of the bar.

The issue I'm facing is that despite the width values appearing to be correct upon inspection (stretched to 100% of container), they don't quite seem to align well enough. The image below illustrates the issue, and "helpfully" delineates the three parts of each bar. When animating, it can be especially noticeable. [Here is a CodeSandbox with sample code demonstrating this issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/zxoqr4y8kl).

I'm seeing this issue in Chrome, mobile Chrome, and mobile Safari. It's not always an issue on Safari. How do I properly make this appear seamless? Is it an issue with my SVGs? My dimensions? Floating point error with percents?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, trying to stack three divs is not the best approach, but it should work mostly.

You can improve the rendering of the top section by rewriting `bar-skew-top.svg` a little:

```
<svg width="150" height="50" viewBox="0 0 150 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <rect id="bar-skew-top-bar" x="0" y="25" width="150" height="25"/>
    <path id="bar-skew-top-cap" d="M75 50L0 25 75 0l75 25-75 25z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

But if I were you, I'd have one single SVG and animate its elements.